# Intersection of two shapely polygon geometries

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, shapely

I have Shapely polygon geometries, A circle(c) and list of polygons within the circle. I want to find the union of the circle with the intersections. (circle + intersections)
[image: circle]

[image: Polygons]

[image: output]

I was trying to make a MultiPolygon of difference and intersection:

```
poly_list = [poly_N, poly_E]

# finding the intersection of circle and polys
intersec_list = []
for poly in poly_list:
    intersec_list.append(circle.intersection(poly))

MP_intersec = MultiPolygon(intersec_list)

# finding the difference of circle and polygons
diff_list = []
for inter in intersec_list:
    diffi = c.difference(inter)

MP_diff = MultiPolygon(diff_list)

# find the union of circle and intersection
# output: a MultiPolygon or a geometric collection with 4 polygons and the difference of circle.  

MP_out = MultiPolygon([MP_diff, MP_intersec])
```

but MP_out gives invalid geometry probably because I have overlapping polygon as well.

Comment: Intersection isn't working because you want something else. Do you want a union or the union of the circle with the intersection? This is the sort of question that screams for a picture.

Comment: I agree with @Vince, a picture often  says a thousand words! I too would say it is a _Union_ you want to do.

Comment: @Vince Yes I want to find the union of circle with the intersection

Comment: By definition, the union of a shape and any shape that it had previously been intersected is the shape itself. A multipolygon cannot be composed of exterior rings that overlap at more than a point.

Comment: Please add a picture which shows  what exactly you need. I recommend you to read [Shapely Manual](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html). It's hard to tell what really you need just by reading your question text and comments.

Comment: You can create a multipolygon including a circle + overlapping region, but it would be an invalid geometry and then it might cause incorrect results in future operations.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz yes I am getting invalid geometry. Is there a way to create geometry collection instead of MultiPolygons? such that I have overlapping region + remaining circle.

Comment: I have added pictures and more detail to the question.

Comment: Yes, you can create geometry collection. I've edited the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no a specific method performing what you want. The following script creates a geometry collection including the circle and intersected areas.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, GeometryCollection

# sample geometries. c: circle, r*: rectangles
c = Point(5, 5).buffer(3)
r1 = Polygon([(1, 6), (1, 9), (9, 9), (9, 6)])
r2 = Polygon([(9, 4), (9, 1), (1, 1), (1, 4)])
rectangles = [r1, r2]

geoms = [c] # create a list including circle
for r in rectangles:
    # add intersection to the list
    geoms.append(c.intersection(r))

# create shapely GeometryCollection
geom_collection = GeometryCollection(geoms)
```

[image: enter code here]

Then, you can get the geometries in the collection.

```
geom_collection.is_valid
# OUT:
# True

geom_collection.geoms
# OUT:
# <shapely.geometry.base.HeterogeneousGeometrySequence at ...>

list(geom_collection.geoms)
# OUT:
# [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at ...>, 
#  <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at ...>,
#  <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at ...>]

# OR use index
geom_collection.geoms[0] # gives the circle, because it is the first element
```

Comment: I have overlapping polygons so MultiPolygon is not working.

Comment: Thank you it is very helpful. What if we want a geometry collection of intersected areas and difference of circle?

Comment: For differences of circle, change `c.intersection(r)` into `r.difference(c)`. If you want the collection not to include the circle, set  `geoms = []` (empty list) instead of  `geoms = [c]`.